# When should GRPC ManagedChannel be shutdown?

Tags: java, grpc, channel, stub

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(host).usePlaintext().build();
```

When I should shutdown the managed channel? Sould it be open all time ? Or Should I close this channel after every operations?

Answer (score 7):

It's intended to be kept open and reused across your application. See for instance this [thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3268) on github, in which one of the contributors states:

> Channels are expensive to create, and the general recommendation is to use one per application, shared among the service stubs.

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown can be used if you see the need to close existing connections(ex: streams) and prevent future connections. A possible scenario is an application exit with a clean state (i.e - finalize all network communications and exit).

However, as Fabian highlighted channels are recommended to be reused where possible. This is further confirmed from the [performance best practices guide](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/)

> Always re-use stubs and channels when possible.